# Use systemd-shutdownd schedule

Tags: centos, rhel, systemd-timer

I have multiple Redhat & CentOS 7 servers that are used only during working hours. I am looking into using the systemd-shutdownd service to shut down each machine at 6-30pm on workdays.

Systemd appears to be a cleaner solution than cron jobs.

Google shows that there is a schedule file that this service uses, but I have not been able to find how to implement it.

Also, I'd like a way to stop the auto-powerdown in case I work late on a particular day.

Comment: Sorry for my first message. I've just putted exact solution.

Comment: fwiw systemd-shutdownd is (was) just the backend to the standard `shutdown`.command. `shutdown` just lets you schedule one shutdown; it doesn't implement a recurring schedule that will run every day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CentOS 7 had `systemd` init system.

`systemd` has a good feature which is named as `timer`. Timer is like service and is intended for starting services at specific time. `systemd` shutdown system by calling `systemd-poweroff` service. So it's need to write `systemd-poweroff.timer`:

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/system/systemd-poweroff.timer
[Unit]
Description=Poweroff every work day
# Call necessary service
Unit=systemd-poweroff.service

[Timer]
# Power off in working days at 23:00
OnCalendar=Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri *-*-* 23:00:00

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

It's need to do `systemctl enable systemd-poweroff.timer` and `systemctl start systemd-poweroff.timer` for enable and run timer. After, timer will be started:

```
$ systemctl list-timers
NEXT                         LEFT          LAST PASSED UNIT                         ACTIVATES
Thu 2018-04-19 19:39:36 MSK  14min left    n/a  n/a    systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
Thu 2018-04-19 23:00:00 MSK  3h 34min left n/a  n/a    systemd-poweroff.timer       systemd-poweroff.service

2 timers listed.

Pass --all to see loaded but inactive timers, too.
```

If you want to disable timer in particular day then it's possible just in case of ordinary systemd service:

```
# systemctl stop systemd-poweroff.timer
# systemctl list-timers
NEXT                         LEFT       LAST PASSED UNIT                         ACTIVATES
Thu 2018-04-19 19:39:36 MSK  12min left n/a  n/a    systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service

1 timers listed.
Pass --all to see loaded but inactive timers, too.
```