# CoreOS: Run a custom script, only once, at boot time

Tags: linux, coreos

I am using the following CoreOS v1688.5.3 [ Rhyolite ] server and i have a specific requirement where i would have to run a particular python script only once, when the server boots up. What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>The simplest was to achieve this is to create in `/etc/crontab` next task:</strike>

```
@reboot /path/to/your/python/script.sh
```

More info you can get from [man 5 crontab](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html).

CoreOS doesn't have `/etc/crontab`.

---

Another way is to create [systemd-timer](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html). Example about systemd-timer you can got from my answer about systemd: [Use systemd-shutdownd schedule](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/438741/use-systemd-shutdownd-schedule/438750#438750).

Simple example of systemd-timer which is located at `/etc/systemd/system/example.timer`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Run once at system boot

[Timer]
# You may chose one of this triggers
OnBootSec=0min # run after system boot
OnStartupSec=0min # run after systemd was started

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target # target in wich timer will be installed
```

Comment: I guess crontab is not available in coreos :( I like the idea of systemd timers, but does the timer allows me to setup a timer only once, during system start up?

Comment: Could i immediately run the script after start up? Like without the 1 min delay? this is because my script tries to change the IP address of server and i want to run it right after the boot. Also is there a way to limit the script to run only once?

Comment: Yes, you can. I correct my example. It's right and guaranteed way to run script once. System booted - after last systemd service is started. Systemd booted - after systemd process in memory and it's located at PID 1.

Answer (score 1):

Using Systemd is the most natural and best way to go:

You need to create a unit for your service in `/etc/systemd/system/yourservice.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=your service name

[Service]
Type=oneshot #or simple
ExecStart=/path/to/your/script.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

To enable the service to run on boot you need to run `sudo systemctl enable yourservice.service` (add `--now` flag to start the script right away)

You do not give much input but there are a lot of other options which you can use in unit file. Check out `man systemd.service` and `man systemd.unit` for more info.

Here is also a link to CoreOS docs:[Getting started with systemd](https://github.com/coreos/docs/blob/master/os/getting-started-with-systemd.md)