# Systemctl Suspend Inside Cronjob

Tags: linux, debian, cron, suspend, systemctl

I have a cron:

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/script 2>/tmp/cron.log
```

And the `script`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
if <some validation>; then
    systemctl suspend
fi
```

So I get the error when cron executed:

```
Call to Suspend failed: Interactive authentication required.
```

Someone have a tip for this? How can I do this works?

Comment: are you running that cron job as root or as your own user?

Comment: @marcus-müller As normal user, I run `crontab -e` from a normal user without `sudo`.

Comment: so, that won't work: your user can't suspend the machine for all users without proving they're sitting in front of it, by default. The easiest solution is not running it as your user, but as root!

Comment: @marcus-müller Let me ask, why I'm able to `systemctl suspend` in a normal terminal emulator?  And if I don't use sudo in my system?

Comment: because you're logged in interactively, so it's proven you're sitting in front of some machine doing some maintenance task

Comment: @marcus-müller Oh, ok that is true.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149949/discussion-between-rhuanpk-and-marcus-muller).

Comment: You'd probably have better luck using a systemd timer - see related [Shutdown, suspend require authentication when scheduled in at](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/464905/shutdown-suspend-require-authentication-when-scheduled-in-at) and this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/438750/65304)